# Can't boot into Windows on new Ubuntu 20.04 dual-boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I have a new work machine. It came with Win 10 on a SATA drive. I added a M.2 drive and put Ubuntu on that. I hardly ever use Windows but occasionally need to.

I can boot Ubuntu fine from grub but when I try to boot Win from grub menu I get "not a valid root device."

I can boot Windoze from the computer's boot menu. The option is something like "UEFI Windows Bootloader." There is also a "UEFI Ubuntu" option there. If I select that option I get a grub menu from which I actually can boot Windows.

Ran bootinfo script. I suspect the recommended repair might be what I need but am hoping someone can advise as I am a little lost on the BIOS vs UEFI thing. Below is a link to the bootinfo script:

https://pastebin.com/te0SiiCG

Comment: Please remove the copy of your report & post the link it gives to a pastebin site as instructed by Boot-Repair. Then it preserves formatting & makes it easier to review.

Comment: Unfortunately, that link doesn't work. Tried it twice and neither link worked. However, I understand that it is difficult to read in the post so I will try something else. Thank you.

Comment: You do not have Windows. You do have both old BIOS Windows boot loader in MBR, and a Windows boot loader entry in UEFI,  but no NTFS partitions. You show 3 partitions, Microsoft reserved, ESP (FAT32) & / (ext4}. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations It looks like you used the erase entire drive choice on install.

Comment: Windows is there because if I use the computer's own boot menu (F9 in this case) I can boot it just fine. Just can't boot it from grub menu. Also, Ubuntu is on the m.2 drive while Windows is on the SATA drive.

Comment: You only show flash drive & NVMe drive. That is then why grub cannot see it as not visible. Is drive hibernated (or fast start up on)? Or is drive set as RAID or Intel RST in UEFI settings? Grub2's os-prober can only add boot entry to drive that it can see. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation If HP use HP UEFI menu (not boot menu) to change default boot order. Best not to mount using device like /dev/sda4. Use label or UUID.